# Complete Action using in My video player

Tags: android, video, whatsapp

I am developing Video Player in which want to add my player in complete action using list for that i will add code in manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*3gp" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*3GP" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*mp4" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*MP4" />
</intent-filter>
```

When I open video from gallery in my player then it work.

In My activity for getting URI of video code:

```
Intent i = getIntent();   
Uri tmpSelectedImageUri = i.getData(); 
filename = getPath(tmpSelectedImageUri, ViewVideo.this); 

 public String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) { 
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };    
    Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);    
    int column_index =  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();   
    return cursor.getString(column_index); 
}
```

Problem is when I open Video from whatsApp to my player it show NullPointerException in this line `Uri tmpSelectedImageUri = i.getData();`

Comment: did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String type = intent.getType();
if (type.equal("text/plain")){
    Log.d("DATA", "Type text: " + intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));
    //tmpSelectedImageUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));
} else if (type.startsWith("video/")) {
    tmpSelectedImageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
}
```